# node.js: get byte length of the string "あいうえお"

Tags: node.js, utf-8

I think, I should be able to get the byte length of a string by:

```
Buffer.byteLength('äáöü')      // returns 8 as I expect
Buffer.byteLength('あいうえお')  // returns 15, expecting 10
```

However, when getting the byte length with a spreadsheet program (libreoffice) using `=LENB("あいうえお")`, I get 10 (which I expect)

So, why do I get for 'あいうえお' a byte length of 15 rather than 10 using `Buffer.byteLength`?

PS.
Testing the "あいうえお" on these two sites, I get two different results

- http://bytesizematters.com/ returns 10 bytes
- https://mothereff.in/byte-counter returns 15 bytes

What is correct? What is going on?

Comment: Using node.js v0.12.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

node.js is correct. The UTF-8 representation of the string "あいうえお" is 15 bytes long:

```
E3 81 82 = U+3042 'あ'
E3 81 84 = U+3044 'い'
E3 81 86 = U+3046 'う'
E3 81 88 = U+3048 'え'
E3 81 8A = U+304A 'お'
```

The other string is 8 bytes long in UTF-8 because the Unicode characters it contains are below the U+0800 boundary and can each be represented with two bytes:

```
C3 A4 = U+E4 'ä'
C3 A1 = U+E1 'á'
C3 B6 = U+F6 'ö'
C3 BC = U+FC 'ü'
```

From what I can see in the documentation, LibreOffice's `LENB()` function is doing something different and confusing:

- For strings which contain only ASCII characters, it returns the length of the string (which is also the number of bytes used to store it as ASCII).
- For strings which contain non-ASCII characters, it returns the number of bytes required to store it in UTF-16, which uses two bytes for all characters under U+10000. (I'm not sure what it does with characters above that, or if it even supports them at all.)

It is *not* measuring the same thing as `Buffer.byteLength`, and should be ignored.

---

With regard to the other tools you're testing: Byte Size Matters is wrong. It's assuming that all Unicode characters up to U+FF can be represented using one byte, and all other characters can be represented using two bytes. This is not true of any character encoding. In fact, it's *impossible*. If you encode every characters up to U+FF using one byte, you've used up all possible values for that byte, and you have no way to represent anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the extra bit. I can't find anything about the LENB-version in Excel (2010). Do you know what Excel is doing on LENB? As the results are afaik the same or similar, they (Excel and Libreoffice) must be doing the same thing ?!